# X11 forward with multiple logins for the same user

Tags: ssh, xorg, x11-forwarding, multiple-users, byobu

we use a server at work which runs byobu. Everyone of my colleagues logs in with the same Debian user account and gets the byobu session presented. This works quite well as we are all sitting in a single room and people can watch each other when working on a byobu console.

But sometimes we have to do X11 forwarding for launching different X11 apps on the server. Everyone of my colleagues has MobaXterm installed which comes with a build in X Server and normally automatically sets the correct display environment variable on login.

The problem: when multiple colleagues are logged in with the same user on server and one is launching a X11 program the window gets opened on the client pc of the first colleague logged in that day.

So always the client which first logged in gets the window open by a second client (both logged in with the same linux user name and password).

I thought this would be a problem of byobu or screen so I added a second user on that server with no byobu attached. Also when two clients connect to the server using the same user name and password the started X11 program is always forwarded to the client first logged in.

Does anyone has a solution for that problem?

Best
Simon